# C# DoDragDrop on Non-Serializable object

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, drag-and-drop

I have a UserControl that can be dragged around my form. I get a first chance exception when the control is accidentally dragged away from my form and into the desktop (as an example):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC))
```

When I start the drag/drop process, I pass in an object of type Control. It is not Serializable nor do I want it to be. Is there a way I can work around this or is there handling for dragging an object outside the host form?

Callstack:

```
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataObject.GetDataIntoOleStructs(ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC formatetc, ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM medium) + 0x175 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataObject.System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject.GetDataHere(ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC formatetc, ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM medium) + 0x70 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataObject.System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject.GetData(ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FORMATETC formatetc, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STGMEDIUM medium) + 0x152 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

Here is another stack, but VS2010 hung so I couldn't copy and paste it. [image: Screenshot]

Comment: I do not want my object to be dragged into the desktop or other applications. MSDN DoDragDrop states: If the drag operation needs to interoperate with applications in another process, data should either be a base managed class (String, Bitmap, or Metafile), or an object that implements ISerializable or IDataObject.

Comment: Is stopping the user from moving the control outside the bounds of your window while they are dragAndDropping an option?

Comment: The only reason why I don't want it because I have no use for dragging outside of my window. The problem is that the program throws an exception.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't clear to me how this exception is getting triggered, the desktop should have no use for your control.  The mouse cursor should show the "cannot drop here" shape.  Nevertheless, first-chance exceptions during D+D are meaningless, they are swallowed and do not otherwise affect the operation.  You only see them because you've got a debugger attached.

If you really want to drill this down then use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for Common Language Runtime exceptions.  The debugger will stop when the exception is raised.  It is quite likely that it is raised inside Winforms plumbing code, you won't have source code to look at unless you enable the Reference Source.  Post the stack trace in your question if you can't figure it out.  Be sure to copy the entire one, scroll it if necessary to get the top activation frame.

But reiterating, this should not be a problem in practice.  The user should see the 'cannot drop' mouse cursor, the exception is swallowed without terminating your program.

Comment: The stack trace isn't deep enough.  Which probably means the code is activated by the drop target, not one of your event handlers.  Nothing you can do about that.  Flip the ignore bit on this.

Comment: It's not exactly clear, but Hans is saying that since this is just a first-chance exception, you can ignore it as long as your program otherwise works as intended. It is usually only unhandled exceptions that you have to worry about.